# How to add a unique id column to a DataFrame, Apache Spark, Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame, that i want to join with another Dataframe, and then group by original rows, but the original rows do not have a unique id. How can i add a unique id or otherwise accomplish that goal.

Comment: can you please add both sample dataframes with  column details ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use monotonically_increasing_id

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val unique_df = original_df.withColumn("UniqueID", monotonically_increasing_id)
```

Comment: I tried to run it as above. But I am getting: No module named monotonically_increasing_id

Comment: Its supposed to work. Did you use that import statement? Also what is your spark version?

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work. This particular import statement did not work for me. I had to change it to: from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

Comment: Will it give me unique from one spark session to other spark session, also is there any way to get fixed 8 digit increrasing_id using this function

Comment: This import path is specific for Scala, if you use Python then use the import of 
user3245256 above

Answer (score 0):

Tawkir showed the working way of doing it in `Scala` via `monotonically_increasing_id`

However, this import:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

does not work for `Python`.

And as user3245256 mentioned in the comments, for `Python` import will be:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
```

BUT. If you want to use UUID as the key then try to adjust your Dataframe with the following in `Scala`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
dataFrame.withColumn("columnName", expr("uuid()"))
```